# QRegExp Usage: How Can I get image names from html string?

Tags: regex, qt5

```
html = ... <span>emoticon12</span><img src="qrc:\res\emoticon\emo12.gif" width="20" height="20"/><span>emoticon8</span><div>...</div><img src="qrc:\res\emoticon\emo8.gif" width="20" height="20"/>...<img src="qrc:\res\emoticon\emo9.gif" width="20" height="20"/>...
```

How can I get all image names as QStringList using QRegExp from html?

result = emo12.gif, emo8.gif, emo9.gif

I can not make regular expression.

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: This is html but it is treated in QString, not as html(only string). So I think I can use regexp.

Comment: I repair your expression (\w+\.[gif]\w+). It works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could parse them with this pattern:  (match is in the first capture group)

```
(\w+\.\w+)"
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/gAzPJo/1/

Comment: Thanks, but there are also .png files. I want only ccc in "/emoticon/ccc.gif"

Comment: I repair your expression (\w+\.[gif]\w+), and it works ok. thanks.